# awscli --api-name flag and usage for kinesisvideo

Tags: aws-cli

I am trying to use the aws cli to work with kinesis video streams.

according to the documentation:

```
aws kinesisvideo get-data-endpoint --stream-name mytestStream
```

should return the data endpoint for my stream but I get:

```
usage: aws [options] <command> <subcommand> [<subcommand> ...] 
[parameters]
To see help text, you can run:

  aws help
  aws <command> help
  aws <command> <subcommand> help
aws: error: argument --api-name is required
```

when I search for `--api-name` I can't seem to find any mention of this flag being needed for `kinesisvideo`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [get-data-endpoint Command Reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/kinesisvideo/get-data-endpoint.html):

```
  get-data-endpoint
[--stream-name <value>]
[--stream-arn <value>]
--api-name <value>
[--cli-input-json <value>]
[--generate-cli-skeleton <value>]
```

> `--api-name` (string)
>
> The name of the API action for which to get an endpoint.
>
> Possible values:
>
> - PUT_MEDIA
> - GET_MEDIA
> - LIST_FRAGMENTS
> - GET_MEDIA_FOR_FRAGMENT_LIST
> - GET_HLS_STREAMING_SESSION_URL